# Is Twilio providing any console where we can see received WhatsApp message?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

Is Twilio providing any console where we can see received WhatsApp message? or always we have to set a webhook in "**WHEN A MESSAGE COMES IN**" textbox to a see received messages?

Answer (score 2):

You can go under the monitor tab from the Twilio Console and click on logs -> messaging to view them.

[image]